# getIntExtra returns only the default value and getStringExtra works

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have this code which calls the activity

```
            Intent intent;
            intent=new Intent(TopicsActivity.this, DisplayTopicActivity.class);

            long nID=5;
            intent.putExtra("TOPIC_ID", nID);

            String strTopicName = ((TextView) viewClicked).getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("TOPIC_NAME", strTopicName);

            startActivity(intent);
```

and this code in the activity

```
            private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
            long nID = intent.getIntExtra("TOPIC_ID", 0);
            String strTopicName = intent.getStringExtra("TOPIC_NAME");
```

strTopicName is returned correctly by getStringExtra, but getIntExtra is returning 0 all the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `Integer` extra. That's why you are always getting zero. Look at the code that you use to put the extra there:

```
long nID=id;
intent.putExtra("TOPIC_ID", nID);
```

The extra with the key "TOPIC_ID" is a `Long`, not an `Integer`.

Either put it in as an `Integer`, or get it out as a `Long`.